# Adding Taskbar context menu to win7 application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, aero

Where can I find documentation about adding a context menu (EDIT: jumplist) to a windows 7 application? You know, when you right click on the application icon on the taskbar. Can I do that using .NET? Or do I need to use native code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the jumplist, you have to do it using WPF (.NET)

EDIT: See [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Jumplists.html)

Answer (score 8):

What I believe you are looking for is the [Windows® API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) and you want create a [Jump List](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows7/products/features/jump-lists) for your application.

> What you see in a Jump List depends
>   entirely on the program.Jump Lists
>   don't just show shortcuts
>
> to files. Sometimes they also provide
>   quick access to commands for things
>   like composing new e‑mail messages or
>   playing music.

**Example:**

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;

JumpList list = JumpList.CreateJumpList();
JumpListCustomCategory category = new JumpListCustomCategory("Links"); 
category.AddJumpListItems(new JumpListLink("http://www.microsoft.com", "Microsoft"));
list.AddCustomCategories(category);
list.Refresh();
```

NOTE: The above example is *untested*, but it should just work™.

I do not know how to make it a command that interacts with the active instance, e.g. like iTunes tasks. I suspect they do an inter-process communication to trigger those actions.

HTH,

Comment: you will not need the Windows API Code pack if you are targeting .NET 4.0 or later (it is built in).

Comment: so I need it if I'm developing a .NET 3.5 app. Don't I?

Comment: some Win7 stuff (including jumplists) is built in to WPF. If @astorcas is not using WPF then the Code Pack is still needed even at .NET 4.

Comment: @Kate: Really? If you already *targeting* the .NET 4.0 Framework then you can easily include the WindowsBase and WindowsPresentation assemblies (i.e. include WPF in the application).