# Adding task options when pinned app is right clicked

Tags: c#, right-click, tasklist, jump-list

We have a c# application that requires a few steps be completed before every launch. I wrote a c# app to automate these steps.

Can anyone help me figure out how I can [EDIT: configure a JumpList] for my app?

I have included a [screen capture](https://dev.alinity.com/LSS/WebClient/TBD/capture.jpg) to hopefully get my point across as I'm not sure how to explain it any better.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156378/adding-taskbar-context-menu-to-win7-application

Comment: The URL is broken now.  This question should probably be deleted, despite the up-votes.

Comment: I tried but get: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Comment: I have voted to close this question.. I don't even use python anymore (for me to try and add more details w/o a picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the native interfaces, see [Taskbar Extensions (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Specifically, I think you're looking for the [ICustomDestinationList::AddUserTasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

If you're using .Net 4+, you can now do a lot of this stuff with built-in classes in the System.Windows.Shell namespace, rather than adding the Windows API Code Pack as suggested by Coding Gorilla. See for example [System.Windows.Shell namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I am 99% of the way there. Only issue is when I try to add the jumplist to my app via [JumpList.SetJumpList(System.Windows.Application.Current, jumplist)] it throws an exception because Application.Current is Null. Any idea what I'm missing?  Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Those are called "Jump Lists", have a look at the Windows API Code Pack [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).  I can't tell you exactly how to implement them, because it's very dependent on your application code.  But this should give you somewhere to start.