# How to add to Windows 7 Start Menu MRU

Tags: windows-7

The Windows 7 Start Menu has a per-entry MRU-like interface.

How do I code my program to work with this? I don't know what to call it so I don't know what to search for.

[image: Windows 7 Start Menu Screenshot]

Example:

```
   Outlook    >> 
   My Program >>  Task 1
                  Task 2
                  Task 3
                  etc
   VS 2012    >>
```

How do I add "Task 1" to my entry programmatically?

Comment: That's called a **Jump List**. You'll see the same entries if you right-click the running/pinned app's icon on the taskbar. Also, since you seem to be interested in code to accomplish this, I'm voting to migrate to SO. (Please refrain from posting a duplicate there.)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156378/adding-taskbar-context-menu-to-win7-application) discusses the programmatic interface to jump lists.

Comment: +1 This was the first Google hit on SO for my fuzzy search "start menu integration mru". I didn't know it's called a jump list either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like unanswered questions, so I'll repeat the correct comments as an answer.

As @Karan mentioned, the circled list is called a Jump List.

As @Raymond Chen mentioned, [Adding Taskbar context menu to win7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156378/adding-taskbar-context-menu-to-win7-application) answers this question.