# How do I call my Un-installer from start Window in Window 8

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a MSI for my WPF app. I am able to install it. After that I get my app in Windows 8 start window. Then I right click on my app icon their. After right click, un-installer option come, when I click on un-installer, it goes to control panel. From their I can un-install my app. But I want to start my un-installer without going to the control panel. Is it possible? If yes, How can I do this?

Comment: Did you add the functionality in the context menu of the app icon to show a Uninstall option?  Are you sure you're right clicking the app icon and not the MSI icon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Taskbar context menu to win7 application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156378/adding-taskbar-context-menu-to-win7-application)

Comment: Same concept as previous comment, [Jump Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491725(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Also, use `msiexec /uninstall [Product Code Here]` to uninstall using command-line.

Comment: @NETscape : I did't not add anything to my app to show this un-install option, in Windows 8, in start page, in any app icon you do a right click, it will show 4/5 option in below bar, where un-install comes. Then If you click on that, it will redirect you to control panel page. From where you can un-install your app. But I want to start un-installation operation before it redirect you to control panel.  This is my application icon. what do you mean by MSI icon